Is there an updated list of Terminal commands to disable animations in Sonoma?
There is a very old post How to turn off all animations on OS X, which lists the following Terminal commands to turn off animations:
defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false
defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
defaults write -g QLPanelAnimationDuration -float 0
defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -bool false
defaults write -g NSDocumentRevisionsWindowTransformAnimation -bool false
defaults write -g NSToolbarFullScreenAnimationDuration -float 0
defaults write -g NSBrowserColumnAnimationSpeedMultiplier -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableSendAnimations -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableReplyAnimations -bool true

I can't speak for the other commands, but defaults write com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations -bool true doesn't seem to have any effect. I ran the above commands in Terminal, then force-relaunched the finder. Folders still animate when I click the chevron in the file list to expand or collapse them.
Is there an updated list of Sonoma macOS settings that can be done via Terminal? I'd prefer to not install any software to mess with my OS for security reasons. (Of course, I'd still have to watch out for malicious Terminal commands.)

DisableAllAnimations might not do what you expect it do (according to the old question, it works on AnimateInfoPanes (whatever this is). Also, asking for a general update to fix one specific issue might not get you the answer you need. Why not focus on the animation effect you want to disable, and ask for a solution?

Why don't you consider posting an updated list?

@nohillside: I actually want to disable all animations, not just a particular one. But, if you want  specific examples, the sliding animation in AppStore whenever you click something. Or the one in my original post, in the Finder whenever you expand or collapse a folder in list view. Or in Weather when you click the chevrons to the left or right of the hours. I am seeking an updated generalized reference.
